# how to print the whole route

Tags: prolog, dcg

Such as for go(a, d). i want it to print the route as well such as route a, route b, route, c and route d

```
door(a, b).
door(b, c).
door(c, d).
door(b, e).
door(e, f).
door(e, g).

go(FromRoom, ToRoom):- 
door(FromRoom,ToRoom).

go(FromRoom, ToRoom) :-  
door(FromRoom, NextRoom),
 go(NextRoom, ToRoom).
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: prolog from 1 door to the next so when i type in go(a,d). it prints out yes but how do i make it print out the full route

Answer (score 2):

Please try not to mix IO and logic in your predicates. It will make your code hard to test, debug, reason about and will produce very confusing output on backtraking.

Here you can keep the road in a list during the recursion.

An example would be, with a third argument:

```
go(FromRoom, ToRoom, [FromRoom, ToRoom]) :-
    door(FromRoom, ToRoom).

go(FromRoom, ToRoom, [FromRoom|Path]) :-
    door(FromRoom, NextRoom),
    go(NextRoom, ToRoom, Path).
```

A query correctly returns the path:

```
?- go(a, g, Path).
Path = [a, b, e, g] ;
false.
```

If necessary, you can then format the output list `Path` when you output it. But it's now a really simpler problem: format a list instead of output things during recursion.

Answer (score 2):

A good way is to simply turn go/2 into a relation that also takes the route into account. As is often the case when describing lists, DCGs are a good fit:

```
go(From, To) --> [From, To], { door(From, To) }.
go(From, To) --> [From],
        { door(From, Next) },
        go(Next, To).
```

Example:

```
?- phrase(go(a, d), Rooms).
Rooms = [a, b, c, d] ;
false.
```

And regarding write/1: This is rarely necessary because we can often let the toplevel take care of printing answers. format/2 is often a better fit than write/1 for formatting output if needed, for example, instead of:

```
write('['), write(From), write(':'), write(To), write(']')
```

you can write:

```
format("[~w: ~w]", [From, To])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the write predicate for this as follows

```
go(FromRoom, ToRoom):-
    door(FromRoom,ToRoom),
    write('['), write(FromRoom), write(':'), write(ToRoom), write(']').

go(FromRoom, ToRoom) :-  
    door(FromRoom, NextRoom),
    write('['), write(FromRoom), write(':'), write(NextRoom), write(']'),
    go(NextRoom, ToRoom).
```

Alternatively, the route in the format you wanted is

```
go(FromRoom, ToRoom):-
   door(FromRoom,ToRoom),
   write(FromRoom), write(' route '), write(ToRoom).

go(FromRoom, ToRoom) :-  
   door(FromRoom, NextRoom),
   write(FromRoom), write(' route '),
   go(NextRoom, ToRoom).
```

Comment: very good help but for go(a,d). do you know how to put it in this format                                                             route a                                                         route b                                                           route c                                                            route d                                                           yes

Comment: @user1232622 you can change the write output to suit your needs. I kind of prefer seeing each link. I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the help this was very hard figuring out

Comment: Mixing IO and logic will fail, especially in Prolog (backtracking here will still print failing branches). This solution is not good.

Comment: @Mog True. But the question did ask for a way to output to console. What do you advise?

Comment: is it because i am missing this symbol !

Comment: @user1232622 Could you please clarify?

Comment: when i type this in 
| ?- go(a, d).
a route b route c route dyes                                                why doesn't it say route a and how do i add the space from route d and yes

Comment: @user1232622: pease try to be clear in your comments. Edit your question if needed.

Comment: ok when i type in go(a, d).                                                  the answer comes up as                                                  a                                                                        route b                                                                route c                                                                 route dyes                                                            can you tell me how to add the route for a so it will say route a and how can i add a space between d and yes

Comment: 1) if this precise output is required because of your homework assignment please add the homework tag. 2) please precise what code are you using and what is the query that led to the result you're mentionning because when I type `go(a, d)`. I don't have the same results as you do.

Comment: i was using the result in which i posted above on the top page

Comment: and did you try out my answer ?

Comment: its a bit confusing to me thats why i am trying to do it with the one i posted

Comment: well if you try to stick to your error prone ways instead of trying to actually understand what could work by asking more clarifications then I wish you good luck and leave it at that.